# How is duration being calculated in a Spark Structured Streaming UI?

Tags: sql, performance, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We have a Spark SQL job that we would like to optimize. We are trying to
figure out which part of our pipeline is slower/faster.

In the attached SQL query graph, there are 3 WholeStageCodegen boxes,
all with the same duration: 2.9s, 2.9s, 2.9s. See the below picture:

[image]

But if we check the Stage graph, it shows 3 seconds for the total stage. See the below picture:

[image]

So the durations in the WholeStageCodegen boxes do not add up, it seems
that these durations refer to the sum of the whole stage. Do we miss
something here? Is there a way to figure out the duration for the
individual boxes?

Sometimes there is some difference in the duration, but not more than
0.1s, examples:

- 18.3s, 18.3s, 18.4s
- 968ms, 967ms, 1.0s
  The Stage duration is always as much as one of the WholeStageCodegen's
  duration, or at most 0.1-0.3sec larger.

How can one figure out the duration for each of the `WholeStageCodegen` parts, and is that actually measured? I suspect that Spark would have to trace individual operations as units of generated functions. Is that measurement actually performed there, or are these numbers more like a placeholder for a feature that does not exist?